# Fetching json file located in the same directory as the blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a blade view called `index.blade.php` and in it i have placed a file called `form.json`

I want to fetch the json file with javascript when the page the lifecycle method mounted mounts like

```
mounted(){
fetch('/form.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res))            
console.log('mounted');
}
```

What path should i use to load the form.json file?

Comment: move your json in your `public` folder

Comment: Any particular reason why i should?

Comment: because `fetch` happens in the user's browser and so the file it retrieves needs to be publicly accessible on the web

Comment: I was hoping i can avoid that and have it sitting it to the actual view. Is there a way i can have it sit next to the actual blade view?

Comment: if you're using something like webpack (or mix) to bundle sources then you can also copy the necessary files to the public folder as part of the build so you can have them where you need them but put them in the public folder when you deploy.

Comment: I can put the forms inside the public like `fetch("{{url('/forms/form.json')}}")` but isnt this a bad idea to have your form structure inside the public directory.

Comment: As I mentioned you can structure your project the way you want but you need to somehow ensure that things that are to be loaded from the client-side are publicly accessible over the web. If you don't want to store them in the public directory to begin with you can copy them there as part of your deployment process using something like webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `__DIR__.'/../views`

```
 fetch('{{__DIR__}}/../views/form.json')
```